# Desabilitar <asp:Button após ser clicado

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Projeto em: WebForm, C#, ASP.net

Preciso desabilitar o botão após ser clicado. Hoje ele está assim:

```
<asp:Button ID="btn_Enviar" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary" Text="Enviar" OnClick="btn_Salvar_Click" data-loading-text="Salvando..." Width="164px" />
```

Tentei na chamada `btn_Salvar_Click`

```
btn_Enviar.enabled = false;
```

Mas não funcionou. Tentei chamar um JavaScript para desabilitar e na melhor das hipóteses ele desabilitou mas não postou (submit).

Como fazer?

---

**Complementando**:
Quando a pessoa clica no botão para salvar o formulário, o sistema demora alguns segundos, fazendo com que a pessoa clique mais uma vez e outra, quando vou ver o sistema cadastrou vários produtos! Por isso gostaria que ao clicar uma única vez, o botão seja desabilitado, assim evito de vários cadastros. Se não conseguir fazer terei que fazer uma lógica para verificar se o produto já foi cadastrado.

Comment: Estranho o ID dele ser btn_Enviar e o evento OnClick ser btn_Salvar_Click, você tem certeza que está mandando para o evento certo? Poderia colocar o código do evento btn_Salvar_Click?

Comment: sim...eu posso criar o nome que eu queira, normalmente o nome é criado com o nome do botão, mas pode ser qualquer um; Esta certo o botão btn_Envir chama o btn_Salvar_Click, que tentei colocar um btn_Enviar.enabled=false; e nada adianta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É que o evento do `button_Click` não pode interferir no comportamento do botão, então tem que ser outro evento pra modificar esse botão.

Coloque no `Page_Load` do seu *Code Behind* o seguinte:

```
btn_Enviar.Attributes.Add("onclick", " this.disabled = true; " + ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(btn_Enviar, null) + ";");
```

Comment: Como sempre você estava certo Cigano, desvendando os mistérios do asp.net..
Coloquei ele dentro da condição:
if (!Page.IsPostBack){

Comment: Só um detalhe cigano, ao colocar esse código, funcionou, desabilitou o botão, porém um textbox parou de enviar, começou a enviar vazio o campo

Comment: Isso não tem a ver com o botão. É alguma outra coisa do seu Form.

Comment: Você teria alguma ideia do pq ela dar esse conflito? creio que seja por causa desse campo ser modificado pelo CKEditor?

Comment: @Dorathoto Não sei. Só debugando pra saber.